# Reorder an array taking each nth element

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm scratching my head on this one. I'm trying to write a function that takes an array `arr` and an integer `n` and outputs a new array made up of each n-th element (starting at index 0) of the original array, returning to the beginning if necessary when the end is reached.

For instance:

```
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
n = 3
output = [0, 3, 6, 9, 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8]
```

Or :

```
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
n = 2
output = [0, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: How about the case arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5] n=3? Then you will only partially cover all the elements in arr.

Comment: Do you want them sorted by value, or index?

Comment: If the length of the array and the value of "n" have a greatest common denominator that's bigger than 1 (that is, if they're not relatively prime), what should happen?  Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
function get_n_elements(arr, n) {
    if ( n === 1 ) return arr.slice();
    var i, j,
        len = arr.length,
        ret = [];
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        for ( j = i; j < len; j += n ) {
            ret.push( arr[ j ] );
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution to the not-relatively-prime issue. It might be good to add the check for `n == 1`.